# Why no 'tab' property in sender object received for chrome.runtime.sendMessage from a sub frame?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

EDIT: Simplified question with MCVE and screenshot of stack.

My MCVE Extension json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TEST SO",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [ "<all_urls>", "tabs" ],
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
}
```

My MCVE content.js:

```
console.log( "content.js Started for Document at " + document.URL );
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage( "'unload' Event for Document at " + document.URL );
});
```

My MCVE background.js:

```
console.log("background.js Started");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function( message, sender ) {
        try {
            console.log( "The 'message' arg is : " + JSON.stringify(message) );
            console.log( "The 'sender' TAB is : " + sender.tab.id );
        } catch ( e ) {
            console.log( "Exception in OnMessage Listener : " + e.message );
        }
    }
);
```

When I navigate from one site with 3 frames (one main frame and 2 subframes, say for exemple https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging-host) to a simple site with one single frame, my background script receives 3 "messages": one for each "unload" event.

Unfortunately, only the first one (corresponding to the "unloading" of the main frame) contains a "sender" argument with a '`tab`' property. The two others have no '`tab`' property.

Documentation states, if I correctly read it, that the '`tab`' propertie should be there.

Is that by design, a bug, or bad code on my side?

Stack showing that the `sender` argument has NO `tab` property.

[image: exception, stack]

Note: You may, at the beginning of the test, be able to have correct `sender` object, but if you then just go back and forth between the 2 sites, you quickly won't be able to have a a `tab` property (for the messages coming from the `unload` in the 2 sub frames)

Chrome `48.0.2564.82 m
Windows Seven 64 bits.`

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which version of Chrome are you using? Can you provide a complete sets of steps to reproduce the problem (sample extension + URLs), and check whether the problem also occurs in a new Chrome profile?

Comment: Re edit: I'm using the same version of Chrome (on Linux), but couldn't reproduce your problem. Please update the question and also include the exact steps to allow me to independently reproduce your problem in a new browsing profile.

Comment: @RobW  Thanks. Added steps.

Comment: @RowW simplified, MCVE.

Comment: Thanks for the MCVE. I did some more testing and created a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582744. You can star the issue to follow its progress.

Comment: @RobW Could you please comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182008/why-does-chrome-fire-unload-on-refresh-but-not-when-using-a-shortcut as I don't understand the comment saying "Chrome somewhat notoriously screws around with the contents of unload handlers (because too many developers abused it)."