# Why does Chrome fire "unload" on refresh but not when using a shortcut?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, addeventlistener

MCVE: a simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
        console.log( "SCRIPT STARTED" );
        window.addEventListener( 'unload', function( event ) {
            console.log( 'UNLOAD EVENT SEEN' );
        });
    </script>
  <head>
    <title>SO QUESTION</title>
  </head>
  <body>o_O</body>
</html>
```

My console shows me `UNLOAD EVENT SEEN` when I hit "Reload this page", or when I use a `A` tag pointing to the page (not included in the MCVE), or when I click to a shortcut to the page in my bookmarks bar.

But when I do other things (like typing another URL in the Address bar, or using another shortcut), there is NO `UNLOAD EVENT SEEN` in my console.

So, `unload` seems to be a pretty standard DOM Event, which should be fired in any case, but it doesn't fire when I go to another page.

What am I missing?
(Chrome 48.0.2564.97 m on Windows 7)

Comment: Chrome somewhat notoriously screws around with the contents of `unload` handlers (because too many developers abused it). `beforeunload` also gets messed with but seems to work for this case at least.

Comment: @DanielBeck `beforeunload` seems to work better, indeed, but with that Event, you can't guarantee that the unload will happen...

Comment: The unload event does fire, it's just not visible in the console. See this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=472282 (and my comment at the end, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=472282#c13)